# Java number guessing game weird output

Tags: java, numbers

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Siddharth's number guessing game. \nThink of a number between 1 and 100 and press 1 to continue");
        Scanner x= new Scanner(System.in);
        if (x.nextInt()==1)
        {
        int high=100;   
        int low=0;
        int guess=(high+low)/2;
        System.out.println("Is your number "+ guess+"? Press 0 if yes, press 1 if your number is higher than this number or press 2 if your number is lower than this number!");
        Scanner y= new Scanner(System.in);
        int ans=y.nextInt();
           while(ans!=0)
           {
               if (ans==1)
               {
                   low=ans;
                    guess=(high+low)/2;
                    System.out.println("Is your number "+ guess+"? Press 0 if yes, press 1 if your number is higher than this number or press 2 if your number is lower than this number!");
                    Scanner y1= new Scanner(System.in);
                    ans=y1.nextInt();
               }
               else if (ans==2)
               {
                   high=ans;
                    guess=(high+low)/2;
                    System.out.println("Is your number "+ guess+"? Press 0 if yes, press 1 if your number is higher than this number or press 2 if your number is lower than this number!");
                    Scanner y2= new Scanner(System.in);
                    ans=y2.nextInt();
               }

           }
           System.out.println("The number you thought is"+guess+"! Thanks for playing!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No problem. Restart the program and press 1 when ready!");
        }
    }

}
```

I have thought a number 22, and entered 2 when it asked me if my number is 50. Then it straight away went to 1. Whatever I enter, it is showing 1 as the output instead of going like 50, 25, 12 etc. I have done the same in Python and C and they work perfectly.

Comment: Why are you creating all these `Scanners` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so, the first problem is that you assign `ans` to `high` and `low` instead of `guess`.

Then, if I can give you some advices:

1. don't create a new Scanner everytime. Instead, always use the same `x` scanner
2. don't put common actions inside each `if/else` block. Instead, put the common operations outside.
3. You can give the instructions (1 for higher, etc) once, and then you simply ask "is your number XX? (0:yes, 1:higher, 2:lower)". It is more readable.

Here is an improved version, but I am sure you can make it even better:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    System.out.println( "Welcome to Siddharth's number guessing game. \nThink of a number between 1 and 100 and "
            + "press 1 to continue" );

    Scanner x = new Scanner( System.in );

    if( x.nextInt() == 1 ){

        int high = 100;
        int low = 0;
        int guess = ( high + low ) / 2;

        System.out.println( "Is your number " + guess + "? Press 0 if yes, press 1 if your number is higher than " +
                "this number or press 2 if your number is lower than this number!" );


        while( true ){

            int ans = x.nextInt();
            if( ans == 0 ){
                break;

            }else if( ans == 1 ){
                low = guess;

            }else if( ans == 2 ){
                high = guess;

            }

            guess = ( high + low ) / 2;
            System.out.printf( "Is your number %d ? (0: yes, 1: higher, 2:lower) ", guess );
        }

        System.out.println( "The number you thought of is " + guess + "! Thanks for playing!" );

    }else{
        System.out.println( "No problem. Restart the program and press 1 when ready!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions!!! Weird me that I did this mistake :P And for that "The number you thought", I was working on it and yet to finish :) Your suggestions are useful. I'll use them. PS: I did not think we can use a scanner more than once( I'm new to Java and new to 'scanners'. Thank you once again

Answer (score 4):

Replace `high = ans`, and `low = ans` by `high = guess`, `low = guess` -- to move corresponding "guessing range" boundary not to value of input (1 or 2), but to value of previous guess, as in binary search.